# Inverse Laplace transform $f(s) = \frac{s^2+2}{s^2(s^2+3)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

> Using partial fractions, find the inverse Laplace transform of the function $$f(s) = \frac{s^2+2}{s^2(s^2+3)}$$

I have tried to separate the whole function using a partial fraction via

$$\begin{align}
\frac{s^2+2}{s^2(s^2+3)} &= \frac{A}{s^2} + \frac{B}{s^2+3} \\
s^2+2 &= A(s^2+3) + B(s^2) \\
s &= \pm\sqrt3, 0
\end{align}$$

I am kind of stuck after this. Am I on the right track?

Comment: So what happens when you plug in $s=0$ or $s = \pm \sqrt{3}$ to your equation $s^2+2 = A(s^2+3) + B s^2$?

Comment: Your partial fraction expansion isn't correct technically speaking, instead of B you should have $Bs+C$ and you should have an additional term of the form $\frac{D}{s}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{s^2+2}{s^2(s^2+3)}&=\frac{A}{s} +\frac{B}{s^2} + \frac{C}{s^2+3}\\
&=\frac{As(s^2+3)+B(s^2+3)+Cs^2}{s^2(s^2+3)}\\
&=\frac{As^3+(B+C)s^2+3As+3B}{s^2(s^2+3)}\end{align}
So equating the powers of $s$ you have $A=0$, $3B=2$ and $B+C=1$ that is $B=2/3$ and $ C=1/3$
and then
$$f(s)=\frac{2}{3 s^2}+\frac{1}{3 (s^2+3)}$$
So you have
$$
\mathcal L\{f(s)\}=\left[\frac{2}{3}t+\frac{1}{3\sqrt 3}\sin(\sqrt 3 t)\right]u(t)
$$